# Performance of Column Family in Cassandra DB

Tags: database, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

I have a table where my queries will be purely based on the id and created_time, I have the 50 other columns which will be queried purely based on the id and created_time, I can design it in two ways,

- Either by multiple small tables with 5 column each for all 50 parameters
- A single table with all 50 columns with id and created_at as primary
  key

Which will be better, my rows will increase tremendously, so should I bother on the length of column family while modelling?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you need to have small tables to decrease the load on single table and should also try to maintain a query based table. If the query used contains the read statement to get all the 50 columns, then you can proceed with single table. But if you are planning to get part of data in each of your query, then you should maintain query based small tables which will redistribute the data evenly across the nodes or maintain multiple partitions as alex suggested(but you cannot get range based queries).

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on how you structure of your partition key & distribution of data inside partition.  CQL has [some limits](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/refLimits.html), like, max 2 billion cells per partitions, but this is a theoretical limit, and practical limits - something like, not having partitions bigger than 100Mb, etc. (DSE h[as recommendations in the planning guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse-planning/doc/planning/planningPartitionSize.html)).

If you'll always search by id & created_time, and not doing range queries on created_time, then you may even have the composite partition key comprising of both - this will distribute data more evenly across the cluster. Otherwise make sure that you don't have too much data inside partitions.

Or you can add another another piece into partition key, for example, sometimes people add the truncated date-time into partition key, for example, time rounded to hour, or to the day - but this will affect your queries.  It's really depends on them.

Comment: But, I will have the range queries based on time, to take average, min, max in that interval, my queries will be like, select column1 where id=id and created_at>time and created_at<time;

Comment: Yes, that's why I mentioned it - if you need to have range queries (it wasn't clear from your question), then you need to make sure that partitions won't be too large - this is typical problem when one `id` is having much more data than other.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of in line with what Alex mentions, the determining factor here is going to be the size of your various partitions (which is an extension of the size of your columns).

Practically speaking, you can have problems going both ways - partitions that are too narrow can be as problematic as partitions that are too wide, so this is the type of thing you may want to try benchmarking and seeing which works best. I suspect for normal data models (staying away from the pathological edge cases), either will work just fine, and you won't see a meaningful difference (assuming 3.11).

In 3.11.x, Cassandra does a better job of skipping unrequested values than in 3.0.x, so if you do choose to join it all in one table, do consider using 3.11.2 or whatever the latest available release is in the 3.11 (or newer) branch.